# Splitting $8$ girls and $8$ boys into two groups with restrictions

Tags: combinations

How many ways can a group of $8$ girls and $8$ boys can be split
into $2$ groups

1. without restriction?
2. if each group contains $2$ girls or $2$ boys?
3. if each group contains $1$ girl and $1$ boy?

For the first question I tried to solve it as $12C6\times 12C6$ (since there are two groups)
For the second one.. $6C2\times 6C4+ 6C2\times6C4$
for the third one... $6C1\times6C5+ 6C1\times6C5$...

I am not sure that I have understood the question correctly.I need to understand the way to divide those groups. 
Thanks a lot :))

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you state its source, include any work you have done on the problem, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is asking for. Are the two groups supposed to be of equal size? Or (for example for the first question) are we allowed to have a group of $2$ and a group of $6$?

Comment: The two groups are supposed to be equal size.That's how I assumed.

Answer (score 1):

(1) We will first solve a **different** problem: How many ways are there to split the group into two teams of $4$, one team to wear blue uniforms, and the other to wear red. That's easy, there are $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to pick the people who will wear blue.

Now we solve our problem. Every one of the $N$ ways to split the group into two teams gives rise to $2$ ways to split them into uniformed teams. So $2N=\binom{8}{4}$ and now we know $N$.

(2) We count the ways to split the group into two *uniformed* teams, each with $2$ girls and $2$ boys. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick the girls who will wear blue, and for each such way there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick the boys who will wear blue, for a total of $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.

Now the reasoning of (1) shows that the number of ways to split into two groups, each with $2$ boys and $2$ girls, is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.

(3) By the reasoning of (1), there are $\frac{1}{2}\binom{8}{4}$ ways to split the group into two teams of $4$. There is only $1$ way to split them so that one team is all girls and the other all boys. So there are $\frac{1}{2}\binom{8}{4}-1$ ways to split the group into two teams, each of which has at least $1$ girl and at least $1$ boy.

**Remark:** The problem is somewhat ambiguous. Another interpretation is that we want to split the group of $8$ into two groups, not necessarily equal in size (except for question (2), where equality is forced). It is not hard to answer (1), but (3) for this interpretation is a bit messy, division into cases is best.